# c# mvc BeginForm adds an id by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OneAction", "OneController", FormMethod.Post,
new
{
    @data_one_attr = "attr",
}))
```

This is a partialView result from "OneAction" (HttpGet). As the action has the same name as the get action the html result is the following:

```
form action="/OneController/OneAction/1" ...
```

If I change the action name in the cshtml file to "OtherAction" the html result is the one I undertand should be the correct one:

```
form action="/OneController/OtherAction/" ...
```

Any idea why is adding that "/1"?

Thanks,

Comment: Well you do have a parameter in the GET method (and it has a value of `1`), but I guess your not going to show the relevant code.

Comment: These are the actions.

public ActionResult OneAction(int id)
{
 return View("_ViewName");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult OneAction(Model model)
{
  ...
}

Comment: What do you think the `(int id)` in your method is - its a parameter named `id` :)

Comment: Change your view code to `@using (Html.BeginForm("OneAction", "OneController", new { id = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { ... })` if you want to remove it (although it makes no sense to remove it and its unclear why you want to do that)

Comment: Hi Stephen. I have tried what you say and it works. but why is it necessary to set the id value to empty when in the BeginForm the name of the action matches the name of the executed action? If it was because there is an "id" parameter, the "/ 1" should always appear, regardless the name we write in the BeginForm. Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Because you navigated to your method by providing a value of `1` for the `id` attribute (e.g. `../OneController/OneAction/1` so it retains that (which is exactly what it should be doing)

Comment: That makes even less sense, but so be it

Comment: If you say it...I don't want to overload the value of the "id" and I want the the same name for the GET and POST actions. Anyway, the answer I was looking was why the "/1" appears when the action name in BeginForm was the same of the action in the controller. I didn't notice about the parameter of the get action.